# D3 updates every path only when select() is running instead of selectAll()

Tags: d3.js, data-binding, data-visualization

I'm trying to update chord diagram according to the changes in data.

I created groups for each element and updated the data binding.
However, for some reason, it updates the data accordingly, only when I go with 'select' instead of 'selectAll' which feels quite odd for me
because everytime I update data binding I have used selectAlll only to update every element related.

My code is as below.

-Creating initial diagram-

```
var g = svg.selectAll('g.groups')
    .data(figureCalculation.groups)
    .join('g')
    .attr('class', (d, i) => { return `group ${nameArray[i]}` })




g.append('path')
    .attr('class', (d) => { return `arc ${d.value}` })
    .attr('d', arc)
    .style('fill', 'grey')
    .style('stroke', 'pink')
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .transition().duration(1000)
    .style("opacity", 0.8);



var chords = svg.append('g')
    .selectAll('path')
    .data(figureCalculation.chords)
    .join('path')
    .attr('class', 'chords')
    .attr('d', d3.ribbon().radius(innerRadius))
    .style('fill', 'green')
    .style('stroke', 'red')
```

-update the data binding-

```
setTimeout(updateData, 2500)

function updateData() {


    figureCalculation = d3.chord()
        .padAngle(0.05)
        .sortSubgroups(d3.descending)(matrix1)


    figureCalculation.chords = [];
    figureCalculation.forEach((d) => {
        figureCalculation.chords.push(d)
    })

    g.select('path').data(figureCalculation.groups)
        .join('path').attr('d', arc)
        .style('fill', 'grey')
        .style('stroke', 'pink')

    chords.select('path').data(figureCalculation.chords)
        .join('path')
        .attr('d', d3.ribbon().radius(innerRadius))
        .style('fill', 'green')
        .style('stroke', 'red')

}
```

The full code is in the following link.

https://codepen.io/jotnajoa/pen/qBaXKVW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SVG` is structured strangely.

First, for your groups, you create a `g` with one child of `path`.  Your update doesn't work because you do a `selectAll` of paths on the `g` with only one child.

Then for your chords that variable is already a collection of `path`.  You are treating it like it's the `g` element holding the `path`.

I'd rewrite your code like this:

```js
let margin = { top: 50, bottom: 50, left: 20, right: 20 }

let width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right;
let height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
let innerRadius = Math.min(width, height) * 0.4;
let outterRadius = innerRadius * 1.2
let svg = d3.select('#graph').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${width / 2 + margin.left}, ${height / 2 + margin.top})`)


var nameArray = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
var matrix = [
    [11975, 5871, 8916, 2868],
    [1951, 10048, 2060, 6171],
    [8010, 16145, 8090, 8045],
    [1013, 990, 940, 6907]
];

var matrix1 = [
    [175, 571, 916, 868],
    [1951, 1248, 2060, 5471],
    [8010, 14145, 4390, 4245],
    [1213, 990, 540, 1207]
];



let figureCalculation = d3.chord()
    .padAngle(0.05)
    .sortSubgroups(d3.descending)(matrix)


figureCalculation.chords = [];
figureCalculation.forEach((d) => {
    figureCalculation.chords.push(d)
})



var arc = d3.arc().innerRadius(innerRadius).outerRadius(outterRadius)

svg
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'groups')
    .selectAll('path')
    .data(figureCalculation.groups)
    .join('path')
    .attr('class', (d, i) => { return `group ${nameArray[i]}` })
    .attr('d', arc)
    .style('fill', 'grey')
    .style('stroke', 'pink')
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .transition().duration(1000)
    .style("opacity", 0.8);

svg
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'chords')
    .selectAll('path')
    .data(figureCalculation.chords)
    .join('path')
    .attr('class', 'chords')
    .attr('d', d3.ribbon().radius(innerRadius))
    .style('fill', 'green')
    .style('stroke', 'red')

function updateData() {

    figureCalculation = d3.chord()
        .padAngle(0.05)
        .sortSubgroups(d3.descending)(matrix1)

    figureCalculation.chords = [];
    figureCalculation.forEach((d) => {
        figureCalculation.chords.push(d)
    })

    svg.select('.groups')
        .selectAll('path').data(figureCalculation.groups)
        .join('path').attr('d', arc)
        .style('fill', 'grey')
        .style('stroke', 'pink')

    svg.select('.chords')
        .selectAll('path').data(figureCalculation.chords)
        .join('path')
        .attr('d', d3.ribbon().radius(innerRadius))
        .style('fill', 'green')
        .style('stroke', 'red')

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.3.1/d3.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="updateData()">Update Data</button>
<div id="graph"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the revised code. Yes I think your code is very easy to follow up. I tried to understand the code of 'Visual Cinammon' https://www.visualcinnamon.com/portfolio/phone-brand-switching but I couldn't figure out why she defined the groups in that way. Maybe I should stick to the way you suggest. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't be sub-selecting in `updateData` at all:

```
g.data(figureCalculation.groups).join(...)
chords.data(figureCalculation.chords).join(...)
```

Comment: I think no matter I sub-select for chords or not, it's working but, if I don't sub-select arc, it doesn't work. Isn't general update pattern like select everything bound to data and update the data and draw things again?